# Adding a clause into a vlookup for specific condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have the current VLOOKUP formula:

```
=VLOOKUP($C$5,Raw!$A$2:$FJ1000,115,FALSE)
```

This works fine, collecting and displaying the relevant data. But if the VLOOKUP corresponds to a blank cell, a ‘0’ is displayed. Can I modify this formula so that instead of ‘0’ it displays "New"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [ISBLANK](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IS-functions-0f2d7971-6019-40a0-a171-f2d869135665) function can pretest the potential result from [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) and compensate for blank entries.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(VLOOKUP($C$5,Raw!$A$2:$FJ1000,115,FALSE)), "New", VLOOKUP($C$5,Raw!$A$2:$FJ1000,115,FALSE))
```

Alternately could you just use the formula you have and apply a custom number format to the cell of `General;General;[Color13]"New"` (with or without the font color change)

Comment: Just beware of doing this on large amounts of data. In that case, rather split the workings over 2 columns, one for the VLOOKUP and one for the ISBLANK.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this. I have not tested this

```
=IF($C$5=ISBLANK(VLOOKUP($C$5,Raw!$A$2:$FJ1000,115,FALSE)),"News",VLOOKUP($C$5,Raw!$A$2:$FJ1000,115,FALSE))
```